# A problem about Hardy-Littlewood maximal function from Folland real analysis book

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For $x \in \Bbb R^n$, define $H^* f(x)=\sup{\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)|\,dy}$, where $B$ is a ball and $x \in B$ and $$H f(x)=\sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)| \, dy.$$ Show that $Hf \leq H^* f \leq 2^n Hf.$

Comment: And with the correct definition ($Hf$ for the centered maximal function, $H^*f$ for the uncentered one), the first inequality is obvious by definition of the supremum, for the second one the hint would be that a ball of radius $r$ containing $x$ is always contained in the ball of radius $2r$ centered at $x$.

Comment: @LukasGeyer Could you explain more about the first one?

Comment: @hil316 You should include the setting, which is apparently $\mathbb R ^n.$

Comment: @zhw. yes, you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We show that $Hf \leq H^* f$ but first we write the definition of your function 
$$
H^* f(x)=\sup_{B \textrm{ ball such that }x\in B}{\frac{1}{m(B)}\int_B|f(y)|\,dy}
$$
and 
$$H f(x)=\sup_{r>0} \frac{1}{m(B(x,r))} \int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)| \, dy.$$ 
So this inequality is obvious because the sup on a large set is almost bigger than the sup on a small one.

*$H^* f\leq 2^n Hf.$

Let $B=B(y,r)$ a ball containing $x$ so $B\subset B(x,2r)$ in fact :
let a $z\in B$ so $\|z-y\|<r$ then 
$$
\|z-x\|=\|z-y+y-x\|\leq \|z-y\|+\|y-x\|<2r
$$
So $z\in B(x,2r)$ and then 
$$
\int_B |f(t)|dt\leq \int_{B(x,2r)} |f(t)|dt
$$
To complete it's enough to proof that 
$$
m(B(x,2r))= 2^n m(B)
$$
First since Lebesgue measure is invariant by translation we have $m(B)=m(B(x,r))$. and it's clear that 
$$
m(B(x,2r))= 2^n m(B(x,r))=2^n m(B)
$$
(because $m(\alpha A +w)=\alpha^n m(A)$)

So 
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{1}{2^n m(B)} \int_B |f(t)|dt &\leq &\frac{1}{m(B(x,2r))} \int_{B(x,2r)} |f(t)|dt\\
\frac{1}{ m(B)} \int_B |f(t)|dt &\leq &\frac{2^n}{m(B(x,2r))} \int_{B(x,2r)} |f(t)|dt\\
H^*f(x) &\leq &2^n H f(x)\\
\end{eqnarray}